# Orthogonal vector closest to target vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

lets say I have two vector **a** and **b** in $R^n$, where $n>3$, I want to find a vector **c** orthogonal to **a** and **b** that is closest to a target vector **d** all of which lie in $R^n$. How would I go about doing that?

I think its, find the basis of the orthogonal compliment of **a** and **b** then project **d** onto that basis?

Comment: Project onto that subspace, yes. Only with an orthogonal basis can you do this by projecting on the individual vectors. Easier: Project $\mathbf d$ onto the span of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ and subtract from $\mathbf d$.

Answer (score -1):

$
\renewcommand\vec\mathbf
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin{{\rfloor}}}
\newcommand\rcontr{\mathbin{{\lfloor}}}
$

You want the *rejection* of $\vec d$ from the plane spanned by $\vec a, \vec b$. I don't know how to do this off-the-bat (though your idea should work), but this is something that is very easy to formulate in [geometric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra), so I'll give a derivation in that language. For simplicity, assume $\vec a, \vec b$ are unit, i.e. $\vec a^2 = \vec b^2 = 1$ (where something like $\vec a^2$ can be interpreted as $\vec a\cdot\vec a$). Then rejection is exactly
$$\begin{aligned}
  \vec d\wedge\vec a\wedge\vec b\rcontr(\vec a\wedge\vec b)^{-1}
    &= \vec d\wedge\vec a\wedge\vec b\rcontr\frac{\vec a\wedge\vec b}{(\vec a\wedge\vec b)^2}
\\
    &= \frac1{(\vec a\wedge\vec b)^2}\Bigl[(\vec d\wedge\vec a)(\vec b\cdot\vec a) - (\vec d\wedge\vec b) + (\vec d\cdot\vec a)(\vec a\wedge\vec b)\Bigr]\rcontr\vec b
\\
   &= \frac1{(\vec a\wedge\vec b)^2}\Bigl[\vec d(\vec a\cdot\vec b)^2 - (\vec d\cdot\vec b)\vec a(\vec b\cdot\vec a) - \vec d + (\vec d\cdot\vec b)\vec b + (\vec d\cdot \vec a)\vec a - (\vec d\cdot\vec a)(\vec a\cdot\vec b)\vec b\Bigr]
\\
  &= \frac{[(\vec d\cdot\vec a) - (\vec d\cdot\vec b)(\vec b\cdot\vec a)]\vec a + [(\vec d\cdot\vec b) - (\vec d\cdot\vec a)(\vec a\cdot\vec b)]\vec b + [(\vec a\cdot\vec b)^2 - 1]\vec d}{(\vec a\cdot\vec b)^2 - 1}
\\
  &= \frac{\cos\theta_{b,d}\cos\theta_{a,b}-\cos\theta_{a,d}}{\sin^2\theta_{a,b}}|\vec d|\vec a + \frac{\cos\theta_{a,d}\cos\theta_{a,b}-\cos\theta_{b,d}}{\sin^2\theta_{a,b}}|\vec d|\vec b + \vec d.
\end{aligned}$$

**Edit:** I want to also note that if $\vec a, \vec b$ are orthogonal then we get the very simple expression
$$
  \vec d -(\cos\theta_{a,d})|\vec d|\vec a - (\cos\theta_{b,d})|\vec d|\vec b,
$$
which is $\vec d$ with the projections onto $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ subtracted out, which I now realize should have been an obvious solution from the outset.